# Why does the order of usage of \captionof matter?

Tags: floats, captions

It seems that the `\captionof` command not only changes the current caption but also all following captions. That means one cannot easily swap captions around in a figure but has to remember what type the float is.

For example,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{capt-of}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\captionof{table}{This is a table}
\caption{This is a figure}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

gives two Table captions while I would have expected the default caption command to just produce the default caption, i.e. Figure ...

Compare:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{capt-of}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\caption{This is a figure}
\captionof{table}{This is a table}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Which gives an expected result.

**Edit:**

Here is my sideways float use case:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{capt-of}
\usepackage{rotfloat}

\begin{document}
\begin{sidewaysfigure}
\captionof{table}{This is a table}
\caption{This is a figure}
\end{sidewaysfigure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: In what situation would you want two different captions?

Comment: The situation is a (whole page) sideways float with both a table and a figure.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The package information string says

> standard captions outside of floats

The problem is that the definition of `\captionof` is rather simplistic:

```latex
\newcommand\captionof[1]{\def\@captype{#1}\caption}
```

Thus if you use `\captionof{table}{...}` inside a `figure` environment, the float type is set to `table` affecting also later `\caption` commands.

Use grouping (or a nested environment such as `minipage`).

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{capt-of}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\begingroup
\captionof{table}{This is a table}
\endgroup
\caption{This is a figure}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, works great. I saw that the original purpose was to have captions outside of floats but it was also recommended elsewhere here that this is a way to have both figures and tables inside of one (whole page) float. I am wondering whether the \captionof command should be extended by your suggestion. But maybe there are unintended side-effects to this in other situations....

Comment: @Daniel in that case you would normally have each part inside their own minipage and thus the `\@captype` change in one will never be seen in the other.

Comment: @daleif Why would one have each part inside a minipage? What is the benefit of this (apart from captionof working as expected)?

Comment: Often: alignment